# How to overcome Javascript “onclick” button to scrape web page with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I want to scrape a website. I scraped table from website but I can not scrape other pages. Unfortunately the pages have no href.

Page hasnt got href when I click other page.I tried .click() but it doesnt work as I expected.I shared html code for button feature. How to scrape all pages not only one.

```
<li class="paginate_button">
<a href="#" aria-controls="datatablezz" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>

    table = soup.find(
            "table", attrs={"class": "table dataTable no-footer"}
        )
        tableBody = table.find("tbody")
        self.rows = tableBody.find_all("tr")

    def addParameters(self):
        for row in self.rows:
            cols = row.find_all("td")
            cols = [sat.text.strip() for sat in cols]
            self.data.append([sat for sat in cols if sat])
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Please explain what you are trying to achieve, what you tried and what was the problem with it. Add your code and error/exception message.

Comment: "Doesn't work", how? It's not informative. Tried `.click()`, why? What is the button for?

Comment: Please share your code and the url if possible. And did you try driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-dt-idx='1']").click()

Comment: https://www.turksat.com.tr/tr/turksat-frekans-listesi This is website and I only scrape table on the page.I want scare all pages' tables

Comment: And please share your current code.

Comment: table = soup.find(
            "table", attrs={"class": "table dataTable no-footer"}
        )
        tableBody = table.find("tbody")
        self.rows = tableBody.find_all("tr")

    def addParameters(self):
        for row in self.rows:
            cols = row.find_all("td")
            cols = [sat.text.strip() for sat in cols]
            self.data.append([sat for sat in cols if sat])

Comment: Beautifullsoup and add every parameter to array which called like data. And you can see code above.

Comment: use both selenium and beautiful soup

Comment: Can you send me relative code about it? Stuck here for real. I must do it in loop I guess upon for loop another loop

Comment: Please add your code to the question using [edit]

Comment: So can we make loop for it somehow ? I cant connect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a method like selenium. You can determine the number of pages and then click on the next button to go through them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.turksat.com.tr/tr/turksat-frekans-listesi')
buttons =  WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".paginate_button ")))
numPages = int(buttons[-2].text) #get last page number
#do something with page 1

if numPages > 1:
    for page in range(2, numPages + 1):
        WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#datatablezz_next'))).click() #click next
        #do something
```

Comment: for page in range(1,self.numPages+1):
            for row in self.rows:
                cols = row.find_all("td")
                cols = [sat.text.strip() for sat in cols]
                self.data.append([sat for sat in cols if sat])
            WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#datatablezz_next'))).click()

Comment: You wanted to click no? Doesn’t the above do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Selenium` and `pandas` it would be very easy to get the table data.However in my way you will get each page table not the whole table.see if this helps.provided sleep to load the page so that can have `page_source`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import pandas as pd
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.turksat.com.tr/tr/turksat-frekans-listesi')
i=2
while i<13:

    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    dfs = pd.read_html(html)
    print(dfs[0])
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='" + str(i) + "']"))).click()
    i = i + 1
```

If you don't have pandas install it is easy to install as well `pip install pandas`

Output will be like below.

```
                        Kanal  Frekans Polarizasyon  ...   V-PID  A-PID Uydu
0                    2000'ler    11012    V - Dikey  ...   120.0    220  T3A
1                       24 HD    12310    V - Dikey  ...  5055.0   5155  T4A
2               24 KITCHEN HD    12460    H - Yatay  ...  2959.0   3059  T4A
3                       24 TV    12298    V - Dikey  ...  3100.0   3200  T4A
4                      360 HD    12310    V - Dikey  ...  5056.0   5156  T4A
5                      360 TV    12298    V - Dikey  ...  3101.0   3201  T4A
6                    42 EN FM    12344    V - Dikey  ...     NaN   5818  T4A
7                         60S    11012    V - Dikey  ...   124.0    224  T3A
8                         80S    11012    V - Dikey  ...   122.0    222  T3A
9                         90S    11012    V - Dikey  ...   121.0    221  T3A
10                    A HABER    11883    V - Dikey  ...  1401.0   1501  T4A
11                    A HABER    12053    H - Yatay  ...  1301.0   1401  T4A
12                 A HABER HD    12053    H - Yatay  ...  1306.0   1406  T4A
13              A HABER RADYO    12053    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   1408  T4A
14                  A NEWS HD    11998    V - Dikey  ...  4905.0   5005  T4A
15                  A PARA HD    11998    V - Dikey  ...  4906.0   5006  T4A
16                     A SPOR    12053    H - Yatay  ...  1302.0   1402  T4A
17                  A SPOR HD    12053    H - Yatay  ...  1307.0   1407  T4A
18               A SPOR RADYO    12053    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   1409  T4A
19                      A2 HD    11998    V - Dikey  ...  4907.0   5007  T4A
20                      A2 TV    12053    H - Yatay  ...  1314.0   1414  T4A
21                     ADA TV    12610    H - Yatay  ...  8005.0   8105  T3A
22                  AKILLI TV    12034    V - Dikey  ...   131.0    231  T4A
23                 AKİT TV HD    12685    H - Yatay  ...  6800.0   6900  T3A
24                    AKRA FM    11509    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   6116  T3A
25                    AKSU TV    12641    H - Yatay  ...  5506.0   5606  T3A
26            AL JAZEERA ARAB    12457    V - Dikey  ...  5308.0   5408  T4A
27         AL JAZEERA ENGLISH    12457    V - Dikey  ...  5307.0   5407  T4A
28      AL QURAN AL KAREEM TV    12729    H - Yatay  ...  5006.0   5106  T3A
29  AL SUNNAH AL NABAWIYAH TV    12729    H - Yatay  ...  5007.0   5107  T3A
30                    ALEM FM    12298    V - Dikey  ...     NaN   3202  T4A
31                   AMBIANCE    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    201  T3A
32                   AMBIANCE    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    201  T3A
33          ANADOLU DERNEK TV    12559    V - Dikey  ...  5406.0   5506  T3A
34                 ANADOLU TV    11976    H - Yatay  ...   151.0    251  T4A
35        ANADOLUDA VUSLAT TV    12514    H - Yatay  ...  6906.0   7006  T3A
36           ANIMAL PLANET HD    12187    V - Dikey  ...   102.0    202  T4A
37              ANTALYA RADYO    11096    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   1018  T3A
38           AROUND THE WORLD    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    268  T3A
39              AS TV (BURSA)    12685    V - Dikey  ...  5805.0   5905  T3A
40                        ATV    12053    H - Yatay  ...  1300.0   1400  T4A
41                 ATV AVRUPA    11883    V - Dikey  ...  1400.0   1500  T4A
42                     ATV HD    12053    H - Yatay  ...  1305.0   1405  T4A
43                      AV TV    12729    V - Dikey  ...  6640.0   6740  T3A
44          AZADLIQ VOA AZERI    11976    H - Yatay  ...     NaN    271  T4A
45                    BABY TV    11012    V - Dikey  ...   176.0    276  T3A
46                    BAROQUE    11012    V - Dikey  ...   125.0    225  T3A
47                  BAYRAK FM    12610    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   8111  T3A
48                  BAYRAM FM    12344    V - Dikey  ...     NaN   5814  T4A
49                  BBC EARTH    11012    V - Dikey  ...   103.0    203  T3A

[50 rows x 9 columns]
                     Kanal  Frekans Polarizasyon  ...   V-PID  A-PID Uydu
0           BBC WORLD NEWS    11012    V - Dikey  ...   115.0    215  T3A
1           BBC WORLD NEWS    11853    H - Yatay  ...  3803.0   3903  T4A
2               beIN GURME    11180    H - Yatay  ...  4457.0   4557  T3A
3                  beIN HD    11675    V - Dikey  ...  3319.0   3423  T3A
4                  beIN IZ    11675    V - Dikey  ...  3306.0   3406  T3A
5       beIN MOVIES ACTION    11180    H - Yatay  ...  4458.0   4558  T3A
6    beIN MOVIES ACTION HD    12072    V - Dikey  ...  4965.0   5065  T4A
7       beIN MOVIES FAMILY    11675    V - Dikey  ...  3316.0   3416  T3A
8   beIN MOVIES PREMIER HD    12072    V - Dikey  ...  4964.0   5064  T4A
9     beIN MOVIES PREMIERE    11180    H - Yatay  ...  4461.0   4561  T3A
10       beIN MOVIES STARS    11675    V - Dikey  ...  3313.0   3413  T3A
11        beIN MOVIES TÜRK    11180    H - Yatay  ...  4456.0   4556  T3A
12      beIN SERIES COMEDY    12072    V - Dikey  ...  4962.0   5062  T4A
13       beIN SERIES DRAMA    12072    V - Dikey  ...  4960.0   5060  T4A
14      beIN SERIES SCI-FI    12072    V - Dikey  ...  4963.0   5063  T4A
15        beIN SERIES VICE    12072    V - Dikey  ...  4961.0   5061  T4A
16         beIN SPORT 1 HD    11675    V - Dikey  ...  3311.0   3411  T3A
17         beIN SPORT 1 HD    11675    V - Dikey  ...  3311.0   3411  T3A
18            beIN SPORT 4    11675    V - Dikey  ...  3307.0   3407  T3A
19           beIN SPORTS 1    11180    H - Yatay  ...  4460.0   4560  T3A
20           beIN SPORTS 2    11180    H - Yatay  ...  4462.0   4564  T3A
21           beIN SPORTS 3    11180    H - Yatay  ...  4463.0   4566  T3A
22       beIN SPORTS HABER    12378    H - Yatay  ...  6421.0   6521  T4A
23    beIN SPORTS HABER HD    12378    H - Yatay  ...  6420.0   6520  T4A
24       beIN SPORTS MAX 1    12072    V - Dikey  ...  4955.0   5055  T4A
25       beIN SPORTS MAX 2    12072    V - Dikey  ...  4956.0   5056  T4A
26              BENGÜ TÜRK    12422    V - Dikey  ...  5101.0   5201  T4A
27                BERAT TV    11916    V - Dikey  ...  6307.0   6407  T4A
28                BERAT TV    12344    V - Dikey  ...  5700.0   5800  T4A
29                BERAT TV    12422    H - Yatay  ...  5203.0   5303  T4A
30            BEREKET AGRİ    12379    V - Dikey  ...  6206.0   6306  T4A
31              BEREKET TV    12457    V - Dikey  ...  5302.0   5402  T4A
32                 BEST FM    12034    V - Dikey  ...     NaN    277  T4A
33                BEYAZ TV    12379    V - Dikey  ...  6200.0   6300  T4A
34             BEYAZ TV HD    12379    V - Dikey  ...  6201.0   6301  T4A
35              BEYKENT TV    12729    V - Dikey  ...  6639.0   6739  T3A
36                  BJK TV    11675    V - Dikey  ...  3318.0   3422  T3A
37            BLOOMBERG HT    11053    H - Yatay  ...  2126.0   2226  T3A
38         BLOOMBERG HT HD    12209    H - Yatay  ...  2002.0   2102  T4A
39         BOOMERANG TV HD    12187    V - Dikey  ...   116.0    216  T4A
40                BROADWAY    11012    V - Dikey  ...   134.0    234  T3A
41                   BRT 1    12610    H - Yatay  ...  8000.0   8100  T3A
42                   BRT 2    12610    H - Yatay  ...  8001.0   8101  T3A
43                  BRT HD    12610    H - Yatay  ...  8002.0   8102  T3A
44             BRT RADYO 1    12610    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   8110  T3A
45                    BRTV    12264    V - Dikey  ...  3415.0   3515  T4A
46                BURSA TV    12264    V - Dikey  ...  3414.0   3514  T4A
47               CANLAR TV    11061    H - Yatay  ...  3077.0   3177  T3A
48          CARTON NETWORK    11976    H - Yatay  ...   115.0    215  T4A
49                CHANSONS    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    249  T3A

[50 rows x 9 columns]
                        Kanal  Frekans Polarizasyon  ...   V-PID  A-PID Uydu
0                    CHILLOUT    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    228  T3A
1             CLASSIC MASTERS    11012    V - Dikey  ...   127.0    227  T3A
2              CLASSICAL CALM    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    258  T3A
3            CLASSICAL GREATS    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    233  T3A
4        CLASSICAL ORCHESTRAL    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    232  T3A
5           CNN INTERNATIONAL    11012    V - Dikey  ...   108.0    208  T3A
6                 CNN TURK HD    12245    H - Yatay  ...   102.0    202  T4A
7                    CNN TÜRK    12034    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    201  T4A
8               CNNTURK RADYO    12034    V - Dikey  ...     NaN    271  T4A
9                   COOL JAZZ    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    230  T3A
10          DA VINCI LEARNING    11012    V - Dikey  ...   104.0    204  T3A
11          DA VINCI LEARNING    11789    H - Yatay  ...  4660.0   4760  T4A
12              DANCE CLUBBIN    11012    V - Dikey  ...   165.0    265  T3A
13                 DEEP BLUES    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    235  T3A
14                    DEHA TV    12264    V - Dikey  ...  3409.0   3509  T4A
15  DIS YAY ORTA DALGA ARAPÇA    11096    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   1316  T3A
16          DISCOVERY CHANNEL    12378    H - Yatay  ...  6412.0   6512  T4A
17       DISCOVERY CHANNEL HD    12187    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    201  T4A
18             DISNEY CHANNEL    12422    H - Yatay  ...  5200.0   5300  T4A
19              DISNEY JUNIOR    11880    H - Yatay  ...  4130.0   4230  T4A
20              DiYANET RADYO    12379    V - Dikey  ...     NaN   6312  T4A
21                 DİYALOG TV    12610    H - Yatay  ...  8003.0   8103  T3A
22      DİYANET RİSALET RADYO    12379    V - Dikey  ...     NaN   6216  T4A
23                 DİYANET TV    12422    H - Yatay  ...  5204.0   5304  T4A
24              DİYANET TV HD    12379    V - Dikey  ...  6203.0   6303  T4A
25                   DİYAR TV    12685    V - Dikey  ...  5814.0   5914  T3A
26               DİZİ PREMIUM    12187    V - Dikey  ...   109.0    209  T4A
27             DİZİ SMART MAX    12187    V - Dikey  ...   114.0    214  T4A
28                       DMAX    12015    H - Yatay  ...  1802.0   1902  T4A
29                    DMAX HD    12015    H - Yatay  ...  1815.0   1915  T4A
30                 DOCUBOX TV    11012    V - Dikey  ...   106.0    206  T3A
31                    DOST FM    12685    V - Dikey  ...     NaN   5941  T3A
32                    DOST TV    12685    V - Dikey  ...  5822.0   5922  T3A
33                   DREAM TV    12034    V - Dikey  ...   105.0    205  T4A
34                 DREAM TÜRK    12034    V - Dikey  ...   107.0    207  T4A
35              DREAM TÜRK HD    12245    H - Yatay  ...   106.0    206  T4A
36                DRT DENiZLi    12729    V - Dikey  ...  6631.0   6731  T3A
37                    DURU TV    12685    V - Dikey  ...  5812.0   5912  T3A
38             EASY LISTENING    11012    V - Dikey  ...   101.0    257  T3A
39                  EDESSA TV    12685    V - Dikey  ...  5809.0   5909  T3A
40                EGE TÜRK TV    12685    V - Dikey  ...  5816.0   5916  T3A
41               EKİN TÜRK TV    11916    V - Dikey  ...  6308.0   6408  T4A
42                    EKOTÜRK    12245    H - Yatay  ...   115.0    215  T4A
43                    ELTR TV    11021    H - Yatay  ...  4194.0   4373  T3A
44         ENGLISH CLUB TV HD    11789    H - Yatay  ...  4659.0   4759  T4A
45                      ER TV    12264    V - Dikey  ...  3412.0   3512  T4A
46                ERKAM RADYO    11509    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   6115  T3A
47              ERZURUM RADYO    11096    H - Yatay  ...     NaN   1216  T3A
48                      ES TV    12605    V - Dikey  ...  5604.0   5704  T3A
49                      ES TV    12685    V - Dikey  ...  5801.0   5901  T3A

[50 rows x 9 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go page by page, all data comes with single request and table render using JavaScript. You should use selector below to get all channels data:

```
div.modal-content
```

You should parse data you need, code exapmle:

```
channels = soup.select("div.modal-content")
print(str(len(channels)))

for channel in channels:
    title = channel.select_one(".modal-title").text.strip()
    ...
```